# record video clip of playing mkv in vlc

Tags: vlc-media-player, recording

I am looking for a easy way to record short sequences with sound in whatever format while watching a mkv or xvid movie. preferably by just hitting a record button for start and stop while watching and then the clip gets saved to the desktop. is this possible with vlc or another video player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC provide the advanced control panel, just click view >  advanced controls and click the red button on the new control panel on the bottom when you want it to start recording, click another time to stop it

Comment: thanks! I was a little confused because the mac version doesn't have the advanced controls option.